# What do you call something you can use twice and not just once?

Tags: word-request

I know there's the word "single-use" as in "single-use plastic bag", but the word "dual-use" is never used to mean "can be used twice", correct me if I am wrong, so is there a word that means that?

For example:

> They invented a ___ syringe that allows a person to use a syringe
>   safely twice without risk of transmitting disease.

Comment: "Dual use" means "can be used two different ways", not "can be used two times".  For example, many arms control regulations deal with "dual use" products that have both civilian (non-military) uses and military uses.

Comment: I don't think there's a word that means it can be used exactly two times and no more.  There's *multi-use* which means it can be used more than once, but doesn't specify exactly how many more times it can be used.  I guess you could say *a two-use syringe* but it would still be a little confusing without more context.

Comment: Specific to a syringe, perhaps *double-dose*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an item would be rare.  In the case of the syringe, is possible for it to be used three times?  In general, if something can be reused, it can be reused many times. It is rare for something to be possible to use exactly twice. In your example, you already say "use...twice" so there is no need for a special adjective.

Saying "dual-use" doesn't work, because that means it has two different uses:

> The dual-use shaver can be used on both your face and your body.

So for this quite rare meaning, you need to use more than one word:

> They invented a syringe *that can be used twice*.